# Could not build a TypeSpec for matrix when model predicts

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

The model works fine on TensorFlow 1.15 (newest release), but does not work on Tensorflow 2.0 when trying to call predict. The model is a Keras Model.

```
model.predict(self.A.todense())
```

Extracted error message:

> /tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/type_spec.py
>   in type_spec_from_value(value)
>
> ```
> 490 
> 491   raise TypeError("Could not build a TypeSpec for %r with type %s" %
> ```
>
> --> 492                   (value, type(value).**name**))
>
> ```
> 493 
> 494
> ```
>
> TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for matrix([[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0,
>   0],
>
> ```
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>     ...,
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
>     [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64) with type matrix
> ```

Comment: same for me. tf2 makes me a lot of troubles

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error come up when I was using Pandas objects, either `DataFrames` or `Series`, as input and target data. It looks like your input is of type `matrix`, in which case this might be your problem as well; an easy fix would be any type conversion, `np.array(self.A.todense())` would likely do the trick.